# I have a 2D MATRIX of chars, and having trouble searching the matrix Spirally

Tags: java, matrix

I start from the left-bottom and proceeding in clockwise direction till no chars are left. here is my code.

```
        import java.io.*;
        import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    static int count = 0;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int m = sc.nextInt();
    int n = sc.nextInt();

    char[][] matrix = new char[n][m];
    char[] temp = new char[n*m];
    for(int r=0;r<n;r++){
        for(int col=0;col<m;col++){
            matrix[r][col] = sc.next().charAt(col);
        }
    }
    int k=0, l = 0;


    while(k < n && l < m){
        if(l<m){
            for(int i = n-1;i>=k;i--){
                temp[count] = matrix[i][l];
                count++;
            }
            l++;
        }

        for(int i = l;i<m;i++){
            temp[count]  = matrix[k][i];
            count++;
        }
        k++;

        for(int i = k;i<n;i++){
            temp[count] = matrix[i][m-1];
            count++;
        }
        m--;

        if(k < n){
            for(int i = m-1;i>=l;i--){
                temp[count] = matrix[n-1][i];
            }
            n--;
        }
    }


    String code = String.valueOf(temp);
    String[] dec = code.split("#");
    //System.out.println(dec);
    int count2 = dec.length;
    System.out.println(count2);
  }
 }
```

So can anyone point out where I am going wrong? I start at left bottom, climb up, go right , then go down, go left and continue till no elements left.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues: incorrect input and missing counter increment.

Incorrect input:

```
for(int r=0;r<n;r++){
    for(int col=0;col<m;col++){
        // The following reads a new line each time a new character is needed
        matrix[r][col] = sc.next().charAt(col);
    }
}
```

This could be fixed either by lifting `sc.next()` from the inner loop:

```
for (int r = 0; r < n; r++) {
    String line = sc.next();
    for (int col = 0; col < m; col++) {
        matrix[r][col] = line.charAt(col);
    }
}
```

Or (preferable) removing inner loop completely:

```
for (int r = 0; r < n; r++) {
    matrix[r] = sc.next().toCharArray();
}
```

Missing increment (lower part of the spiral):

```
for(int i = m-1;i>=l;i--){
    temp[count] = matrix[n-1][i];
    // Counter increment is missing. Add
    // counter++;
}
```

In general, is is better to use `StringBuilder` for gradual construction of the string. In you case it will look as following:

```
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
<...>
temp.append(matrix[n-1][i]);
<...>
String code = temp.toString();
```

In this code you don't have to estimate possible string size nor manually track current insert position.

Comment: Lower part of spiral as in?

Comment: You could find it in the source code by the loop header `for(int i = m-1;i>=l;i--)`.
`

Answer (score 0):

starting left bottom in the matrix is

```
    matrix[0][m];
```

going up the hill will be made by decreasing m to a point where you already had a char inserted.
i would use 4 for loops inside a while loop like is presented:

```
    while (usedRow < (int)0.5*n && usedCol < (int)0.5*m)
    {
         //usedRow and usedCol start with the value of 0 and will be raised
         // by the end of the loop
         int i, j;
         for (i = m - usedCol; i<=(m-usedCol); i++)
          { 
              matrix[usedRow][m-i] = sc.next().charAt(0);
          }
          for (j = usedRow; j <= (n-usedRow); j++)
          {
              matrix[n + j][usedCol] = sc.next.charAt(0);
          }
          for (i = usedCol; i <= (m-usedCol); i++)
          {
              matrix [n - usedRow][m+i] = sc.next().chatAt(0);
          }
          for ( j = n - usedRow; j <= (n - usedRow); j++)
          {
              matrix[n - j][m - usedCol] = sc.next().charAt(0);
          }
          usedRow++;
          usedCol++;
    }
```

this way you go clockwise and keep the loop within the rows and cols that are not in use.

hope that it helped you in a way.